# Creating Sequence of Sequences is Causing a StackOverflowException

Tags: recursion, f#, sequences

I'm trying to take a large file and split it into many smaller files. The location where each split occurs is based on a predicate returned from examining the contents of each given line (`isNextObject` function).

I have attempted to read in the large file via the `File.ReadLines` function so that I can iterate through the file one line at a time without having to hold the entire file in memory. My approach was to group the sequence into a sequence of smaller sub-sequences (one per file to be written out).

I found a useful function that Tomas Petricek created on fssnip called [groupWhen](http://fssnip.net/6A). This function worked great for my initial testing on a small subset of the file, but a StackoverflowException is thrown when using the real file. I am not sure how to adjust the groupWhen function to prevent this (I'm still an F# greenie).

Here is a simplified version of the code showing only the relevant parts that will recreate the StackoverflowExcpetion::

```
// This is the function created by Tomas Petricek where the StackoverflowExcpetion is occuring
module Seq =
  /// Iterates over elements of the input sequence and groups adjacent elements.
  /// A new group is started when the specified predicate holds about the element
  /// of the sequence (and at the beginning of the iteration).
  ///
  /// For example: 
  ///    Seq.groupWhen isOdd [3;3;2;4;1;2] = seq [[3]; [3; 2; 4]; [1; 2]]
  let groupWhen f (input:seq<_>) = seq {
    use en = input.GetEnumerator()
    let running = ref true

    // Generate a group starting with the current element. Stops generating
    // when it founds element such that 'f en.Current' is 'true'
    let rec group() = 
      [ yield en.Current
        if en.MoveNext() then
          if not (f en.Current) then yield! group() // *** Exception occurs here ***
        else running := false ]

    if en.MoveNext() then
      // While there are still elements, start a new group
      while running.Value do
        yield group() |> Seq.ofList }
```

This is the gist of the code making use Tomas' function:

```
module Extractor =

    open System
    open System.IO
    open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

    // ... elided a few functions include "isNextObject" which is
    //     a string -> bool (examines the line and returns true
    //     if the string meets the criteria to that we are at the 
    //     start of the next inner file)

    let writeFile outputDir file =
        // ... write out "file" to the file system
        // NOTE: file is a seq<string>

    let writeFiles outputDir (files : seq<seq<_>>) =
        files
        |> Seq.iter (fun file -> writeFile outputDir file)
```

And here is the relevant code in the console application that makes use of the functions:

```
let lines = inputFile |> File.ReadLines

writeFiles outputDir (lines |> Seq.groupWhen isNextObject)
```

Any ideas on the proper way to stop groupWhen from blowing the stack? I'm not sure how I would convert the function to use an accumulator (or to use a continuation instead, which I think is the correct terminology).

Comment: I did something similar to this for a Hadoop / MR implementation in F# - https://github.com/isaacabraham/HadoopFs/blob/master/HadoopFs/Core.fs#L9-L24

Comment: Looks interesting @IsaacAbraham thanks. I'll have to check out the project to expose myself to some more real-world F#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with this is that the `group()` function returns a list, which is an eagerly evaluated data structure, which means that every time you call `group()` it has to run to the end, collect all results in a list, and return the list. This means that the recursive call happens within that same evaluation - i.e. truly recursively, - thus creating stack pressure.

To mitigate this problem, you could just replace the list with a lazy sequence:

```
let rec group() = seq {
   yield en.Current
   if en.MoveNext() then
     if not (f en.Current) then yield! group()
   else running := false }
```

However, I would consider less drastic approaches. This example is a good illustration of why you should avoid doing recursion yourself and resort to ready-made folds instead.

For example, judging by your description, it seems that `Seq.windowed` may work for you.

Comment: Ah yes you're right. I see the Seq.ofList call now too, at the bottom of the groupWhen function. Changing this to a sequence for the entire operation seems to work, thanks! I was not aware of Seq.windowed. I'll have a look at that and see if I can come up with a solution that fits there as well.

Comment: There are actually _two_ `Seq.toList` calls in this code, but you only see one of them. The square brackets in the `group()` implementation - they get translated into a call to `Seq.toList`, too. And it is this second call that I meant in my answer.

Comment: Yes I understood that. I just meant that I also saw the Seq.ofList call further down in the code, which was required because the group() implementation had the square brackets (create a list) rather than the curly braces (create a sequence).

Answer (score 6):

It's easy to overuse sequences in F#, IMO. You can accidentally get stack overflows, plus they are slow.

So (not actually answering your question),
personally I would just fold over the seq of lines using something like this:

```
let isNextObject line = 
    line = "---"

type State = {
    fileIndex : int
    filename: string
    writer: System.IO.TextWriter
    }

let makeFilename index  = 
    sprintf "File%i" index

let closeFile (state:State) =
    //state.writer.Close() // would use this in real code
    state.writer.WriteLine("=== Closing {0} ===",state.filename)

let createFile index =
    let newFilename = makeFilename index 
    let newWriter = System.Console.Out // dummy
    newWriter.WriteLine("=== Creating {0} ===",newFilename)
    // create new state with new writer 
    {fileIndex=index + 1; writer = newWriter; filename=newFilename }

let writeLine (state:State) line = 
    if isNextObject line then
        /// finish old file here    
        closeFile state
        /// create new file here and return updated state
        createFile state.fileIndex
    else
        //write the line to the current file
        state.writer.WriteLine(line)
        // return the unchanged state
        state

let processLines (lines: string seq) =
    //setup
    let initialState = createFile 1
    // process the file
    let finalState = lines |> Seq.fold writeLine initialState
    // tidy up
    closeFile finalState
```

(Obviously a real version would use files rather than the console)

Yes, it is crude, but it is easy to reason about, with
no unpleasant surprises.

Here's a test:

```
processLines [
    "a"; "b"
    "---";"c"; "d"
    "---";"e"; "f"
]
```

And here's what the output looks like:

```
=== Creating File1 ===
a
b
=== Closing File1 ===
=== Creating File2 ===
c
d
=== Closing File2 ===
=== Creating File3 ===
e
f
=== Closing File3 ===
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, this is along the lines of how I first tried to approach the problem. I felt like I wasn't being idiomatic enough as far as the `F# way` of doing things (I"m trying to stop writing C# style code in F#). This approach definitely works though and probably would be how I would do it if I couldn't get the groupWhen function working. Although I am tempted to change it (as you say, it is easier to reason about).

Comment: One of the things I like about F# is that it is pragmatic, so I don't have to worry too much about some perfect style.  My code is perfectly functional though --  it uses immutable objects, higher-order functions, etc. One thing I would do is to make it more testable (and pure) by removing any references to IO and File and have the needed dependencies passed in as functions too. Then the whole thing could be mocked trivially.

Comment: Also, I would be wary of forcing the problem into a solution. The sequence of sequences is cool, but I'm not sure your problem really matches that technique other than in a superficial way. For example, if the parsing logic between file segments become more complicated, or you needed to write the new files in parallel while continuing to read the main file, the seq of seq implementation might start getting in your way rather than being helpful. Just my 2c :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll have to be careful of that for sure. It's all part of the learning process I guess. Now off to F# for fun and profit I go for some more reading...